# graph theory and maximal independent sets

Tags: graph-theory

Show that there is a unique graph on n nodes that is connected and such that a maximal independent set of that graph involves all nodes except node $i$.

No idea how to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a connected graph of size $n$ such that a maximum independent set of that graph involves all nodes except $i$. Since all nodes that are not $i$ form a maximum independent set, there is no edge between any of them. Since $G$ is connected, the only possible path between two nodes must be through $i$ so they're all connected to $i$.

Thus, the only possible graph satisfying your condition is the graph where all nodes different of $i$ have edges to $i$ but not between themselves. You can easily check that such a graph does indeed satisfy the condition. Existence and uniqueness.

Comment: @user472423 No problem. If you're satisfied with the answer you should accept it so it gets out of the "unresolved" queue.

Comment: Don't have high enough reputation so I can not do that...

Comment: I didnt know you needed reputation for that, fair enough. Have a nice day.

Comment: It worked. :) Thanks once again you really helped me a lot. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Let $a,b$ be two nodes that are both $\ne i$. Can you determine whether or not there is an edge $ab$?

**Second:** Let $a$ be a node $\ne i$. Given the answer to "First", can you determine whether or not there is an edge $ai$?